# Modified trigonometric system

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We know that the trigonometric system $\left\{e_{n}=
e^{2 \pi i n x}
\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is complete in $L^{2}[0,1]$, using this fact, is there a smart way to show $
\mathcal{E}_{b}=\left\{e^{2 \pi i b n x}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}
$ is complete in $
L^{2}\left[0, b^{-1}\right]
$ for $b>0$ a fixed scalar?

Answer (score 2):

Let $d$ be the dilation $d:[0,1/b] \rightarrow [0,1]:x \mapsto bx$.  Then observe
$$  e_n \circ d= \mathcal{E}_n $$
and
$$  e_n = \mathcal{E}_n \circ d^{-1}  \text{.}  $$

Try using this on $f \in L^1[0,1/b]$ as $f \circ d^{-1} \in L^1[0,1]$, so from
$$  f \circ d^{-1} = \sum_i a_i e_i  \text{,}  $$
it is immediate that 
$$   f = \sum_i a_i e_i \circ d = \sum_i a_i \mathcal{E}_i  \text{.}  $$
That is, push $f$ forward from $[0,1/b]$ to $[0,1]$ using $d$, apply completeness there, then pull back using $d^{-1}$.

Comment: Is it possible that $d$ may not be invertible?

Comment: @maskliesink : Not in the context of the problem as given.  $d^{-1}:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1/b]:x \mapsto x/b$.